Programming an MCU for the first time using USB
I am trying to develop my own telemetry board which would use an accelerometer, GPS module, display etc. , I am currently doing the schematics for my board. I would like to programm the MCU just using USB (I want to get experience using USB), however I have never used USB. I will probably be using PIC16F19185T-IPT which supports ICSP.
I read that an USB-to-UART bridge would work. However, when I read the datasheet for ICSP programming I figured out that it basically needs ICSPDAT, ICSPCLK and MCLR pins, which is totally different from UART. What if I used the bridge IC and write my own code for GPIO pins which would then be used for ICSPDAT and ICSPCLK? Would that work?
Now I basically do not know what to do. I have read so many posts about using USB for programming and I am confused.
What are the options when I do not want to use a programmer like Pickit 5 but USB instead?
I have tried to use the CP2102N so I can communicate with the mcu directly via USB. Then I realised that I would have to programm the mcu for the first time and that is only via ICSP.

It's not possible to program an MCU for the first time using USB.  Your MCU doesn't even have a USB interface.  Other MCUs that have built-in USB peripherals do not come preprogrammed with USB drivers.  It seems like you've figured this out on your own.  Why do you persist?  The ICSP and Pickit are right there.

You could of course use some small device acting as virtual serial interface over USB to the PC and as ICSP driver to the PIC. But this resembles just the mentioned programmers. :-D Either way you need a programmer, ready-made or built yourself. Even if you find a USB-to-SPI dongle to adapt, I'd call this a programmer.

You can certainly program some mcus for the first time using USB, a number from st support this.  But it appears you are looking specifically for the PIC family.  This is no different in say being a mechanic, you need a number of tools in your toolbox including uart, and other (as well as usb cables themselves, something to power a board with, etc).  For example adafruilt has an FT232H board.  The ftdi parts with mpsse can support many protocols without much effort (uart, i2c, spi, jtag, swd, etc).  and there should be many breakout boards out there.

from there you then need to create or find a tool (again this is part of your mcu developer toolbox) or eventually be able to create a tool, that can program whatever the interface is be it i2c, spi, uart, etc or some custom interface that you bit bang...PICs have been around forever though and likewise programming solutions, including virgin parts, should be a dime a dozen.  And some percentage of those this day and age should be able to be accessed either directly via usb or another usb board to connect to the programmer board.

I don't know about modern PICs, but in the past they were known as hard-to-program with something else than Microchip's programmer and Microchip's software. Seems this MCU supports bootloader, so if you can find (or write your own) bootloader and flash it once, you probably can program MCU over USB-to-serial adapter.
